# How to optimize double select query

Tags: mysql, optimization

```
SELECT  `id`, `field2`, `field3`, `field4` as Title FROM `articles` 
WHERE `category_id` = 'X' 
AND `id` NOT IN 
(SELECT `articleid` FROM `article-seen` WHERE `userid` = 'Y')
```

How can I optimize this?
I think double select is bad, but im new to mysql

Answer (score 0):

Try using JOIN that will get you the same result but makes the query looks simpler

Comment: My problem is that this query can run up to 20 times per page if user select multiple categories.

Comment: why can't you do category_id IN (X,Y,Z) when user selects multiple categories?

Comment: that responses are shown separately, but your question gives me a new idea

Comment: to explain my schema:
userid -> category_subscribe - category_id(1 or more) -> categories (with category_id now I can get all info about category) with foreach I echo data and run THIS query to get what articles user didnt see to print them for each category_id.

Answer (score 0):

The optimization depends (I think) on the version of MySQL you are using.

This is how you write it as a `join`:

```
SELECT  `id`, `field2`, `field3`, `field4` as Title
FROM `articles` a left outer join
     `articles_seen` arts
     on a.id = arts.articleid and arts.userid = 'Y'
where a.`category_id` = 'X' and
      arts.id is null;
```

This query, at least, doesn't materialize the subquery, which (I think) your originally query would.

To makes this faster, you want to add indexes.  The ones that come to mind are: `articles(category_id, id)` and `articles_seen(userid, articleid)`.  You could also add the fields in the `select` to the first index, so the entire query can be satisfied by looking at the index, rather than returning to the main table.

Comment: about version is 5.5.31

Comment: with your example i created another query with JOIN and my website loading is great now.